# using \thanks in pandoc

Tags: yaml, pandoc

according to the pandoc manual, a variable "thanks" can used in the YAML of a markdown file to replicate Latex's \thanks command, like so:

```
---
title: super awesome paper
author: albert enstein
thanks: university of alberta
---
```

but instead it puts the asterisk on the title and not the author, where it is supposed to go.

**EDIT** How do I put thanks on the author and not the title with pandoc?

Comment: you'll have to use a custom [template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates)..

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already points out, you will probably need to create a custom template. The behaviour you describe is the proper behaviour of the /thanks command.

What you want looks like the authors affiliation section for a titlepage. This can be accomplished using the institute variable in the YAML header. It is only supported in a few document classes. The code from it can be found in the default latex template (`pandoc -D latex`):

```
$if(institute)$
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}
\institute{$for(institute)$$institute$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$
```

Try this instead of the thanks variable, just lookup which classes supports this prior to your tests.